# change Linux thread priority to real time SCHED_FIFO

Tags: pthreads

I am trying to change Linux thread priority to real time SCHED_FIFO by pthread_setschedparam. I am getting error "no permission".

I am getting this error when the process is executed under root (sodo).

What is correct way to change Linux thread priority to real time SCHED_FIFO?

Answer (score 0):

There were two reasons for the problem.

First, user limits weren't configured in the /etc/security/limits.conf.
Both hard and soft rtprio should be configured.
Here is an example:

myusername hard  rtprio 65

myusername soft  rtprio 65

The details about limits' configuration can be found in the file limits.conf itself.

Second, the kernel (usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/.config) is configured with parameter CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED set to y.

In order to use real time priorities with CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED corresponding control group (cgroup) should be created and configured.

See:
[https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-rt-group.txt][1]
[https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/ch01
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/cgroups.7.html
][2]